# rvm and GEM_PATH after Capistrano deployment; can't access "rails c"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rvm

I am using Capistrano to deploy to a Ubuntu 11.10 host using rvm and ruby 1.9.2-p290. This appears to be working fine.

Passenger / nginx is set up correctly and it is serving up rails pages fine. The issue is that I have gems now in a couple of places.

Gem environment gives me:

```
GEM PATHS:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
```

but rails is installed in **$appname/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems** . I'd like to run `rails c` but can't. How would I fix this?

**edit #1**
This is hosted at Linode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was originally running:

```
bundle exec rails c
```

but, was getting permission issues, so you must provide the env:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c
```

or better yet:

```
bundle exec rails c production
```

Answer (score 1):

if you used:

```
bundle install --path <path>
```

then you need to run the gems with:

```
bundle exec rails c
```

you could also use:

```
bundle install --path <path> --binstubs
```

and change `PATH`:

```
PATH=$appname/bin:$PATH
```

or use the bundler hook in rvm:

```
chmode +x $rvm_path/hooks/after_cd_bundler
```

which will update the path when you:

```
cd $appname
```